# Convert Hair into volume mesh or surface

Tags: mesh, hair

I'm trying to import hair simulation in realflow to make fluid drip on it.
The problem is that i need to make the beard being a volume instead of edges or curves so i can triangulate them.
Is there a way to wrap a mesh on the beard to simulate a surface or just a way to convert the whole beard as a mesh?

Thanks a lot,
Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking *Convert* on the particle modifier instance will convert the particles to a mesh object. Make sure you delete/hide the old particle system otherwise you'll have a duplicate floating around.

[image]

Then convert that object to a curve object.

[image]

Set the curve bevel to some small number to give it any amount of geometry, just so its not an infinitely thin curve.

[image]

Use the same previous command to convert that back into a mesh.

[image]

Then use voxel remesh to get a simple "meshified" version of the hair object.
[image]

[image]

It's highly likely that there is a better way to do this, but this is just what I managed to figure out.

Comment: i will try this i think it might work well ! thanks a lot !